# How to get GMSPlacePickerViewController's navigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I need to change the tint color of the GMSPlacePickerViewController's navigationBar. But when I try to get the navigationController, it's returning nil. So if anyone knows, please help me.

Comment: What do you want actually?

Comment: At which point of the view's life cycle (e.g. `viewDidLoad()`, `viewDidAppear()`, etc.) are you quering the `navigationController` property?